# Regular expression: how to ignore block of text

Tags: regex

I use some macros in my HTML enclosed in {..}. I parse it before HTML output. Regex is looks like `/\{(.*?)\}/` (I simplified it for example). But later I found the problem. If HTML contains JavaScript then it is corrupted when it contains curly braces. 
So I need to apply my regex to text that is not inside `<script...></script>` tags. How it can be done?

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: oh, another html and regex story...